# Adding any control to an existing C# Windows form corrupts the display

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition w/ .Net 4.8 but the same behavior presents itself with Visual Studio 2019 Professional w/ .Net 4.6.1

What is happening is that I can clone a new Feature branch from Git to my local system and when I launch it everything is fine. The main application form presents itself just fine and I can get to all of the buttons, dropdown lists, file selectors just fine. The minute that I had any new control to the form when I subsequently launch the application the form is cut in half and I can't get to any of the controls and maximizing the form doesn't help either. When I inspect the designer code things have been drastically moved around in the post modification file as compared to the original. I've included sample information--

Original Form Display
[image: Correct form display]

Post Modification Form Display
[image: Modified form display]

Designer Code Compare Sample
[image: Designer code compare sample]

A team member can take the same code base and add controls without any problems. Additionally he took my codebase which runs fine on his system compiled it and sent me the executable and when I launched that executable I had the problems with form display that my solution exhibits.

One final not thinking it was my laptop I got a brand new laptop and I'm still seeing the issue. I also created an AWS EC2 Instance and tried it there with the same behavior.

We're all stumped here none of us has ever seen behavior like this. We're hoping that someone in the Community has seen this sort of thing before and can shed some light on the issue.

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: how is the property AutoScaleMode of the form set ? Do you use Large Fonts on your windows ?

Comment: [Make your application DpiAware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms) (in .Net Framework, you have to opt-in), scale to DPI instead of Font. Design at 100% scale (VS issues a warning when you don't) -- Use nested containers (anchored / docked Panels, TableLayoutPanels, FlowLayoutPanels) to setup the layout of your Controls -- With .Net 4.8, use app.config to specify a `PerMonitorV2` DpiAwareness

Comment: So I followed the instructions in the 'Make you application DpiAware' and set my Design scaling to 100% and it's working like a charm. Thank you so much - I'm going to pass this information on to the rest of my team